# Error: unexpected ',' in "df = read.csv(("/home/rstudio/IMDB_data.csv" ,"

Tags: r

```
df = read.csv(("/home/rstudio/IMDB_data.csv" ,header=T ,fileEncoding='latin1', sep=",")[-2,])
```

I wrote the above R code to remove the second line in a file, however it is not working.

This process was already shown in a previous example here, But it's giving me error message `unexpected : ','`

Comment: You mentioned a previous example, but didn't include a link to it. Is that error a copy paste of the entire message, or is there more to it?

Comment: Please format code as code (not as normal text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
df = read.csv("/home/rstudio/IMDB_data.csv" ,header=T ,fileEncoding='latin1', sep=",")[-2,]
```

Comment: How to rearrange the index ?.. I see the index skipped , as i skipped the row

Comment: Of course it did.  df$index <- 1:nrow(df) will create a new one.

Comment: Please mark the question answered and begin a new thread as your analysis reveals further issues. Thank you